# Adding together factor levels across multiple columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I've got a dataset with the same four factors repeated over a number of columns. I'm trying to count the number of factors in each column (in effect adding the rows together) but without any success using the `summarise( n = n())` command. Instead of getting a no. of columns x 4 size dataframe, I get just the entire thing counted.

This is the code I've tried:

```
percentages_20_notconstant <- allchangingreaders_20    %>% 
 
  group_by(resp) %>%
  summarise(resp = n(colnames(allchangingreaders_20)))
```

```
structure(list(resp = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("Don't Know", 
"Leave", "Remain", "Will Not Vote"), class = "factor"), euRefVoteW1 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 17L, 10L, 0L, 5L, 
13L, 9L, 0L, 3L), euRefVoteW2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 
0L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 16L, 12L, 0L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 0L, 5L), euRefVoteW3 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 11L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 17L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 
13L, 8L, 0L, 4L), euRefVoteW4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 
2L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 19L, 10L, 0L, 3L, 12L, 8L, 0L, 5L), euRefVoteW6 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 8L, 0L, 4L, 
13L, 7L, 0L, 5L), euRefVoteW7 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 
1L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 12L, 0L, 2L), euRefVoteW8 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 12L, 0L, 1L, 
12L, 12L, 0L, 1L), euRefVoteW9 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 
0L, 12L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 21L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 14L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have managed to do what I was after by changing a seperate function, but think this task is something which makes sense to keep up.
So the thing I'm trying to do is to go from  the first dput to this dput:

```
structure(list(resp = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("Don't Know", 
"Leave", "Remain", "Will Not Vote"), class = "factor"), euRefVoteW1 = c(45L, 
24L, 1L, 9L), euRefVoteW2 = c(43L, 27L, 0L, 9L), euRefVoteW3 = c(44L, 
21L, 1L, 13L), euRefVoteW4 = c(46L, 22L, 0L, 11L), euRefVoteW6 = c(50L, 
19L, 0L, 10L), euRefVoteW7 = c(44L, 32L, 0L, 3L), euRefVoteW8 = c(45L, 
32L, 0L, 2L), euRefVoteW9 = c(48L, 31L, 0L, 0L), Paper = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Former Readers", class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Can this be done with `summarise` ?

Comment: Apologies, this should work now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this

```
allchangingreaders_20 %>% group_by(resp) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~sum(.)))

# A tibble: 4 x 9
  resp   euRefVoteW1 euRefVoteW2 euRefVoteW3 euRefVoteW4 euRefVoteW6 euRefVoteW7 euRefVoteW8 euRefVoteW9
  <fct>        <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>
1 Don't~           9           9          13          11          10           3           2           0
2 Leave           24          27          21          22          19          32          32          31
3 Remain          45          43          44          46          50          44          45          48
4 Will ~           1           0           1           0           0           0           0           0
```

Answer (score 2):

After grouping by 'resp', get the `rowSums` of the `cur_data()` (which doesn't include the grouping column) and then wrap with `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
allchangingreaders_20  %>% 
     group_by(resp) %>% 
     summarise(n = sum(rowSums(cur_data())), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  resp              n
#* <fct>         <dbl>
#1 Don't Know       57
#2 Leave           208
#3 Remain          365
#4 Will Not Vote     2
```

---

Or if it is the count of elements greater than 0

```
allchangingreaders_20  %>% 
    group_by(resp) %>%
    summarise(n = sum(rowSums(cur_data() > 0)))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  resp              n
#* <fct>         <dbl>
#1 Don't Know       20
#2 Leave            27
#3 Remain           32
#4 Will Not Vote     2
```

#### Update

Based on the updated expected output, we can also do

```
allchangingreaders_20  %>% 
     group_by(resp) %>% 
     summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum), .groups = 'drop')
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, this is very useful. I've managed to do the thing I was after by altering another function further up in my workstream and have included the output I was after as a second `dput()`. In particular, I was trying to keep the seperate columns: is there a way to do this ?

Comment: @jolene Based on the expected, you just need to sum individual columns grouped by 'resp' .  I think the other answer showed it correctly.  If you had updated earlier, it would have been much better

Comment: Apologies, though I think I had updated by the time of the other answer. If I didn't make that clear, sorry. Thanks for your time !